# What is a substate contracts max storage size? using the contracts pallet

Tags: ink, storage, substrate-contracts-node

Just to clarify, I am not asking about the max upload size of a contract. I am able to upload my contract to my chain no problem.

I have two smart contracts (A,B) A calls a transaction on smart contract B when smart contract A is deployed. This was working absolutely fine, I made sure that the contracts were funded, so it is not the case the the contract ended up in tombstone state. Then out of nowhere i got an error when deploying Contract A, I got a ContractTrapped Error.

I investigated more deeply and it was not an error with Contract A. I was able to deduce this from the fact that when contract A called a copy of B, it worked fine.

Looked deeper into this and it turns out I could not make any transactions on Contract B at all, but could still query the data stored in it.

So i looked into the contract StorageDeposit over time

```
  const r = range(573000, 574000, 1);
  r.map(async (block) => {
    const hash = await api.rpc.chain.getBlockHash(block);
    const apiAt = await api.at(hash);
    const contract = await apiAt.query.contracts.contractInfoOf(
      "5CAwMPDocR23HDDsLC2RqR4CFFZkgvjR7PsPtrKyK1qhdkNv"
    );
    const timestamp = await apiAt.query.timestamp.now();
    console.log(
      `StorageDeposit at block ${block} is ${
        contract.toJSON()?.storageDeposit
      } and timestamp is ${new Date(timestamp.toNumber())}`
    );
  });
```

And I found this was the issue

- StorageDeposit at block 573007 is 1382380000000 and timestamp is Mon Jan 02 2023 13:03:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
- StorageDeposit at block 573008 is 1382580000000 and timestamp is Mon Jan 02 2023 13:03:06 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

The contract StorageDeposit maxed out at 1382580000000, which also explains why i can read the state of the smartcontract, but not add more.

So ultimately my question is, where on the contracts pallet configuration can i increase this?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the [`storage_deposit_limit`](https://docs.rs/pallet-contracts/latest/pallet_contracts/pallet/enum.Call.html#variant.instantiate_with_code) as part of your message/instantiation call [in cargo-contract](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/blob/c84f8641e576225bb3ed0fb2773322d615b4bc49/crates/cargo-contract/src/cmd/extrinsics/call.rs#L295)